# GIT GUI - Windows - How do I start the output command window in maximized mode for custom tools?

Tags: git, git-gui

I have added a series of tools (custom git commands) to my GIT GUI for windows. Every command has the option to display an "output" window for activities. Every time I select a tool, it opens the non-maximized floating window showing the output. Is there any way to start it maximized and on the same monitor as the GIT GUI window? Much appreciated.

Comment: According to irc.freenode.net's git channel, this is currently not possible